# Inline youtube video doesn't work in cordova application on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, youtube, youtube-api, cordova-3

I develop a mobile application with cordova, and I really need to be able to play inline youtube video.

I tried to resolve it for a while:

- I set the attribute `playsinline` to `1` in the youtube iframe API
- I put `<preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true"/>` in my config.xml
- Then I set `AllowsInlineMediaPlayback` to `true` in the plist in Xcode
- I even try to put webkit-playsinline directly on the iframe

The results are weird. When I play my video the first time, it goes fullscreen. So I inspect my HTML via the remote developer tools to check if the attribute is well set. It is! I do as I would edit it, I leave it without modification, and the magic happen: my video plays inline!

Obviously, I can't ask my users to do this trick.

Someone have an idea to solve this out?

It's kind of an emergency issue...

Comment: This worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34002561/inline-youtube-video-in-ionic-cordova-phonegap-app-on-ios-iphone/34009907#34009907

Answer (score 3):

There are several conf files in the folder cordova,
the one that worked in my case with IOS is /Staging/config.xml
Try to add to this conf file:
 preference name = "AllowsInlineMediaPlayback" value = "true"

Answer (score 3):

More specifically you can add this in preference as @Patrice Tadrif mentioned in above answer in Cordova config.xml

```
<platform name="ios">
    <preference name="AllowsInlineMediaPlayback" value="true">
</platform>
```

Comment: watch out for the closing tag

Answer (score 0):

The name="AllowsInlineMediaPlayback" is not correct. The actual cordova preference name is "AllowInlineMediaPlayback" (note the missing 's' from 'Allows'). So the config.xml entry should look like this instead:
atrice Tadrif mentioned in above answer in Cordova config.xml

```
<platform name="ios">
    <preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true">
</platform>
```

Also, in the html `<video>` tag, don't forget to pass the `playsinline` attribute.

This is how I've found about this problem: https://medium.com/thecreative-cat/allowinlinemediaplayback-is-not-allowsinlinemediaplayback-1a9123fdf88c

Comment: watch out for the closing tag

Answer (score -1):

For me, it was just a case of using the correct preference name, you were missing the "s" from "Allows". So it should be:

```
<preference name="AllowsInlineMediaPlayback" value="true">
```