# Inline YouTube video in Ionic/Cordova/PhoneGap app on iOS/iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, youtube, ionic-framework

How can I get a YouTube video to play inline in an Ionic/Cordova/PhoneGap app on iPhone? I've tried all the top results on here and Google to no avail. Whether I embed with an iframe, an object, or via the YouTube iframe api, the video always opens in full screen.

There are lots of iOS apps which achieve this. How are they achieving this? And can this somehow be hijacked and implemented into a Cordova app? Via a Cordova plugin, for example?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the Youtube video should display inline initially and expand upon playing. If you're using an `iframe`, you might want to set the fullscreen `fs` attribute to `0` and `playsinline` to `1`. Might want to check out [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters).

Comment: Thanks, this was 1 part of the solution, I've posted the full answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally got this working.

First, insert the YouTube video like so:

```
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item"  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XL9528Gohe0?autohide=1&playsinline=1&showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

Next, close down Xcode and edit *config.xml* (usually in the root of your project).

Add this line under the other preferences:

```
<preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true" />
```

Save it, rebuild the project, open in Xcode and run again. Your YouTube video should now be playing inline. Tested on latest iOS (9.1) on iPhone 6.

Comment: Me did not work. I followed his every step and nothing. In the place where it should appear the youtube video, it is only a blank space.

Comment: Need to mention one thing. In config.xml, should add this line: `<allow-navigation href="*://*.youtube.com/*" />`

Comment: I've looked and looked for a solution. Nothing worked. Thank you for posting something complete. This finally allowed me to get youtube videos to play within my app. Followed Zhou Hap's and your preferences settings.

Comment: @Danny youtube video started playing but i have list of items containing <img tag/>that actually loads thumbnail images from youtube ... that's not downloading any image in iPhone Cordova while its working for android

Comment: in my case the video plays only in full screen any work around ? i think it's because of the width of iphone because it works on ipad

Answer (score 4):

As @Zhou Hao added in a comment, you also need

```
<allow-navigation href="*://*.youtube.com/*" />
```

Without it, it was working fine in Android, but nothing was displayed in iOS (the content of the iframe was `<html><body></body></html>`).

After adding it, it worked fine on iOS also.

This is with Cordova iOS 4.2.0.

Comment: Tested on iOS 8.3 (Cordova iOS 6.0) and it works. Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Use should use`playsinline` as player parameter according to the documentation. [youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Parameters)