# Annoying behaviour of Iframe with Ionic Mobile App

Tags: android, iframe, ionic-framework

I have created an ionic app. It gets a list of video from youtube channel and displays it in a view using `<ion-list>` after the tap on one of the `list item` app moves to next view where I set Iframe for a youtube video.

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/gvI2ClWqHO0?feature=player_embedded" frameborder="0" width="560" height="315" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

After play video if I press `back button` of mobile app moves back to my first screen where a list of all videos available. But the issue is that if a video is playing in fullscreen mode and I press back button app doesn't back to the previous screen it just exits the `app`.

I tried different question in [stackoverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com) but nothing to solve my problem yet.

**Info Update**

Currently, I am focusing only on Android

Comment: Does this answer helps you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34002561/inline-youtube-video-in-ionic-cordova-phonegap-app-on-ios-iphone

Comment: @ItaloAyres, No it doesn't solve my problem. I tested that it still exit my app if I tap on a back button while video playing in full-screen mode.

Comment: Have you tried handling the backButton event? I'm sure ionic has a way to do this.

Comment: I tried that too. For a test, I put the only alert in `backButton` event. It alerts when I press mobile's back button. But when iframe playing video in fullscreen mode and I press back button app still close without alerting anything.